# Reproduce a time in shiny using Bookmark

Tags: r, time, shiny, bookmarks

I am trying to create a shiny app in which one is able to set a specific date, time and value and save those in a URL. That way, when you want to enter a second set of values, you won't have to again enter those first values.

I succeeded saving dates and numeric values; However, for some reason when using timeInput (from shinyTime) for setting a specific time, it resets after bookmarking and pasting the URL. Any suggestions how to prevent the time from resetting or how to circumvent this?

### Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyTime)

ui <- function(request) {
          fluidPage(
          titlePanel("Test"),
          bookmarkButton(label = "Save"),
          dateInput("d1",
                    "Date",
                    format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                    value =  ""),
          
          timeInput("t1", "Time", seconds = FALSE),
          numericInput("b1",
                       "Value",
                       value = ""),
          mainPanel(
                    textOutput("selected_var")
          ))}

server <-     function(input, output, session) {


          output$selected_var <- renderText({ 
                    paste("The date is",
                          paste(input$d1, strftime(input$t1, format="%H:%M")),
                          "with the following value:",
                          paste(input$b1)
                          
                          )})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

Comment: You should file an issue [here](https://github.com/burgerga/shinyTime/issues) asking to make `timeInput` "bookmark" aware.

Comment: For future readers: [Here](https://github.com/burgerga/shinyTime/issues/15) you can find the according issue.